# Inversion of control based on properties file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Below is my interface :-

```
 interface Student {
       findById();
    }
```

Below are my 2 implementations of interface :-

```
class Matriculation implements Student {
   findById(){
      //implementation
    }
}
class Graduation implements Student {
     findById(){
     //implementation
     }
}
```

application.properties

graduation=true

Calling class :-

```
class Test {

@Autowired 
Student student ;
   
   method(){

   student.findById();
 }
}
```

If graduation is true i want to call Graduation class findById else i want to call Matriculation findById method .How can i achieve this in SpringBoot?

Comment: Simply use if else condition check for value using @Value for graduation (String/Boolean).

Answer (score 1):

you can use the @ConditionalOnProperty annotation. Like this:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "graduation", havingValue = "true")
@Service
public class Graduation implements Student
{
  @Override
  public String findById()
  {
    return "Graduation";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

correctly indicated in comments, here is a possible implementation.

```
class Test {

   @Autowired 
   Matriculation matriculationStudent ;

   @Autowired
   Graduation graduationStudent;

   @Value("${graduation}")
   private boolean graduation;
   
   void method(){

   if (graduation) {
   graduationStudent.findById();
   } else {
   matriculationStudent.findById();
   }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're gonna create a Spring Component like this:

```
@Component
public class StudentFactory {

    @Autowired
    private Matriculation matriculation;

    @Autowired
    private Graduation graduation;

    @Value("${graduation}")
    private boolean graduationValue;

    public Student getImplementation() {
        if (graduationValue) {
          return graduation;
        } else {
          return matriculation;
        }
     }

}
```

and then you just inject the factory in the Test class and call `getImplementation` method